# iOS UIWebView and Cookies storage

Tags: ios, angularjs, cookies, uiwebview, session-cookies

I use Cordova 4, Angular 1.4 and Ionic 1.3 to make a tablet app for Android and iOS.

When user synchronised datas, app opened another window ([cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)) and displayed our SSO webpage. When user ended to connect, window was closed and synchronisation was send again.

Android store session cookie when app is closed but iOS don't.
Each time user open app on iOS, he need to open window authentificator.

Is it a way to store much longer cookies on iOS ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EVURLCache](https://github.com/evermeer/EVURLCache)  may help you.

> This is a NSURLCache subclass for handeling all web requests that use
> NSURLRequest. (This includes UIWebView)
>
> The EVURLCache is meant for handeling the following caching
> strategies:
>
> - The app has to be functional even if there is no internet connection.
> - The app has to be functional right after the app has been downloaden
>   from the app store. (This means that the required content can be
>   included in the app.)
> - You do want to be a able to download new/updated
>   content if it's available.

## Note:

Support: `iOS 8+` `OSX 10.9+` `WOS 2+` `TVOS 9+`